# Firefox supports mp3

Tags: firefox, audio

I'm working on a web site with an audio player. As it is known, Firefox supports `ogg` format and Chrome `mp3`.

However, after a Firefox upgrade, now Firefox is supporting `mp3`, as it is playing the songs with `mp3` format.

Does Firefox supports now `mp3` format? If not, why is it supported just doing an upgrade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mozilla should pay royalties if they include a mp3 decoder in their applications. But they can circumvent that by using the decoder of the operating system and that's what they are doing with Firefox. If the operating system supports playing mp3's Firefox supports it too.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats#MP3

IMO, to support as many browsers as possible I would use a combination of a proprietary and an open source codec like mp3 and Ogg Vorbis.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using that combination and works fine. Just was surprised because of the `mp3` support.